# Array in foreach shows only first array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I am busy with a foreach loop but i can't find the problem.
This code show only first array, and stops. The problem comes from the array in the foreach loop.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$catarray = array();
$catslug = array();

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $array2 = array (  
            'name' => $term->name,  
            'slug' => $term->slug,
            'id' => $term->term_id
        );

        $product_cat = $array2;
        //$product_cat = $term->name;
        break;
    }
    array_push( $catarray, $product_cat );
endwhile;

$categorielijst = array_unique($catarray);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($categorielijst);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

The result is:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Salades
            [slug] => salades
            [id] => 67
        )

)
```

And if i change
$product_cat = $array2;
for 
$product_cat = $term->name;

Than is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Salades
    [1] => Aardappels
    [3] => Diverse fruit
    [4] => Blad groentes
    [5] => Schulp sappen 100% fruit en groentes
    [8] => Groentes
    [11] => Uien
    [13] => Verse kruiden
    [19] => Dressings kiooms
    [25] => Appels
    [28] => Paddenstoelen
    [32] => Tomaten
    [34] => Bananen
    [35] => Citrus fruit
    [37] => Peren
    [49] => Verse sla
)
```

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: What i want is: 
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Salades
            [slug] => salades
            [id] => 67
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Aardappels
            [slug] => aardappels
            [id] => 23
        )

        [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Diverse fruit
            [slug] => diverse-fruit
            [id] => 11
        )`
etc. etc.

Comment: why are you calling `break;` this will break out of the loop?

Comment: Addition to @atoms `$product_cat`'s value will be overwritten in every loop if removed `break`. should be `$product_cat[] = value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your foreach to work as followed:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {

    $array2 = array (  
        'name' => $term->name,  
        'slug' => $term->slug,
        'id' => $term->term_id
    );





    $product_cat[] = $array2;
}
```

As requested, the output should be something like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Salades [slug] => salades [id] => 67 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Aardappels [slug] => aardappels [id] => 23 ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Diverse fruit [slug] => diverse-fruit [id] => 11 )
```

Break was causing you to exit the loop after one iteration. And as mentioned by Sougata you would be overwriting `product_cat` unless you append it with `product_cat[]`

UPDATE: Assuming that you want to sort arrays and 'id' is unique:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {

    // check if its set, if not add it!
    if(!isset($product_cat[$term->term_id])){
        $product_cat[$term->term_id] = array('name'=>$term->name, 'slug' => $term->slug);
    }

}
```

Comment: Output result is:
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Salades
                    [slug] => salades
                    [id] => 67
                )

        )

)`

Comment: is that still only the first iteration then? if so check to make sure your DB call is returning the data you expect

Comment: Your right the result is good, now i want to filter the duplicated arrays.. if i put `array_unique($product_cat);` than i get one array again..

Comment: you dont need to use array_unique for that. Just check if it exsists already before adding it. N.B. you shouldnt get the rows from DB unless you need them. This is probably a DB issue

Comment: '    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Salades
            [slug] => salades
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Aardappels
            [slug] => aardappels
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Salades
            [slug] => salades
        )
'

Comment: Hi there, the solution was good. But it is a paged page so on page 1 you see not all terms and on page 2 you see diffrent. But i want that we get all the terms. and i cant find wich Query vars i actually needed. Who can help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the

`break;`

and put

`array_push( $catarray, $product_cat );`

into the foreach loop

```
$catarray = array();
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $array2 = array (  
            'name' => $term->name,  
            'slug' => $term->slug,
            'id' => $term->term_id
        );

        array_push( $catarray, $array2 );
    }

endwhile;
$categorielijst = array_unique($catarray);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($categorielijst);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Hi there, the solution was good. But it is a paged page so on page 1 you see not all terms and on page 2 you see diffrent. But i want that we get all the terms.